# How BufferedInputSteam helps to work with large files?

Tags: java, io, out-of-memory

I have an application, which works with large files (gigabytes). Sometimes I get an `outofmemoryerror` exception. Does it  help if I wrap `InputStream` in `BufferedInputStream`? What purpose of `BufferedInputStream`? How it works?

Comment: *"`OutOfMemomy` exception."*  No such thing in Java.  Please copy/paste these things.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356137/read-large-files-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not help you with memory consumption. It will help you speed up reading the file if you happen to read it in very small chunks.

What *will* help you, is not to keep the entire file in memory at once. Just keep the parts you're currently processing.