# Java: How to read huge records (>10k)

Tags: java, arraylist, java-io

Looking for best practice to read a file line by line which has >10 records and storing it in `ArrayList`.

My program was able to read to 3.5k records and ignoring rest of the records.

```
URL cityurl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(citypath);
citybr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cityurl.getFile()));
for (String city = citybr.readLine(); city != null; city = citybr.readLine()) {
    citycountryairport.add(citybr.readLine());
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It might be helpful if you identify what you don't like about your current solution. Is it running out of memory? Something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read large files in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356137/read-large-files-in-java)

Comment: Hint: read about java naming conventions. Variables go camelCase!

Comment: You can eliminate duplicate code by changing loop to `for (String city; (city = citybr.readLine()) != null; )`. That also more closely resembles the more common `while ((city = citybr.readLine()) != null)` loop used for `readLine()` processing.

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader is a good choice for reading large files because it buffers the file and thus avoids loading the whole file into memory, see [BufferedReader Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Each time you call

```
readLine();
```

The next line of the file is read, in your code change :

```
citycountryairport.add(citybr.readLine());
```

to :

```
citycountryairport.add(city);
```

otherwise the lines read by the line

```
city = citybr.readLine()
```

will not be added to your list because you never add the String *city* to your list.

Comment: A little more explanation might be good, but very nice observation, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks! I've made some edits, hopefully OP understands

Comment: @Mwanza, My code isn't throwing any exception but it is printing null and ignoring rest of the records in case I use readLine() method.. but your suggestion worked perfect!!            why is this happening with direct approach? a little more explanation will be nice. Thank you!!

Comment: The records were not being ignored, you were reading the records using

Comment: The records were not being ignored, remember that each time `readLine()` is called, the _next line_ of the file (if any) is read. For each iteration of your loop, you were reading a line using `city = citybr.readLine()`, the contents of this line were saved in the _city_ variable, you were not adding the city String to your list. You then called `citycountryairport.add(citybr.readLine())` , which read in the following line  _and_ saved it to you list, hope this helps, maybe have a look at [for loop docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), you're welcome :-)