# Java 8 zipfile > 4 GB . ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Tags: java, zip

I'm having this error with java `1.8.0_60` on a `zipfile` > `4 GB`

I found that should be possible through zip64.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zippedFile);
```

Error :

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
```

Should I get the entries in another way to use zip64 ?

Comment: You could try a [java zip filesystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) - would be interesting.

Comment: If the resulting zip file is malformed (like you have) then the most likely cause is that you are not closing the file.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: zip file is valid

Comment: @JoopEggen: same error for zip > 4 GB with java zip filesystem

Answer (score 5):

I would do like this:

```
FileInputStream fInput = new FileInputStream(zipFileName);
ZipInputStream zipInput = new ZipInputStream(fInput);
ZipEntry entry = zipInput.getNextEntry();

while(entry != null){
  String entryName = entry.getName();
  File file = new File(destinationFolder + File.separator + entryName);

  // Do whatever you need with the file here
}
```

Cross topic for large files : [Read large files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356137/read-large-files-in-java)

Comment: This did it without error. Thanks. I voted up but I don't have enough reputation yet to see it apparently.

Comment: I tried it further and found some performance issues with it. I'm just interested in getting the zipentries. With "new ZipFile(file)" I'm getting them instantly. With the stream I get the impression it loads the entire file to get the entries. Do you have an idea how to proceed or should I open a new thread?

Comment: So you don't want to read what's inside the entries but just a list of the ziped files ?

Comment: Right, first I have to know the entry's name before doing something with it. Afterwards I make a stream with some of the entries and pass them to the database.