# What is Mapped Buffer Pool / Direct Buffer Pool and how to increase their size?

Tags: java, performance, scala

[image]

The screenshot of VisualVM was taken when I ran an IO intensive JVM program (written in Scala), heap size was 4 GB and only 2 GB were in-use. The JVM program uses memory mapped file.

What does "mapped buffer pool" and "direct buffer pool" mean?

Those pools seem to be very full. Since the JVM program uses memory mapped file, will I see increased performance if the pools were larger? If so, how to increase their size?

The size of all mapped files are about 1.1GB in size.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**Direct Buffer**

A [direct buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) is a chunk of memory typically used to interface Java to the OS I/O subsystems, for example as a place where the OS writes data as it receives it from a socket or disk, and from which Java can read directly.

Sharing the buffer with the OS is much more efficient than the original approach of copying data from the OS into Java's memory model, which then makes the data subject to Garbage Collection and inefficiencies such as the re-copying of data as it migrates from eden -> survivor -> tenured -> to the permanent generation.

In the screenshot you have just one buffer of 16KB of direct buffer. Java will grow this pool as required so the fact the blue area is at the top of the block is merely a statement that all buffer memory allocated *so far* is in use. I don't see this as an issue.

**Mapped buffer pool**

The mapped buffer pool is all the memory used by Java for its [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) instances.

Each FileChannel instance has a buffer shared with the OS (similar to the direct buffer with all the efficiency benefits). The memory is essentially an in-RAM window onto a portion of the file. Depending on the mode (read, write or both), Java can either read and/or modify the file's contents directly and the OS can directly supply data to or flush modified data to disk.

Additional advantages of this approach is that the OS can flush this buffer directly to the disk as it sees fit, such as when the OS is shutting down, and the OS can lock that portion of the file from other processes on the computer.

The screenshot indicates you have about 680MB in use by 12 FileChannel objects. Again, Java will grow this is Scala needs more (and the JVM can get additional memory from the OS), so the fact that all 680MB is all in use is not important. Given their size, it certainly seems to me that the program has already been optimized to use these buffers effectively.

**Increasing the size of the mapped buffer pool**

Java allocates memory outside the Garbage Collection space for the FileChannel buffers. This means the normal heap size parameters such as `-Xmx` are not important here

The size of the buffer in a FileChannel is set with the [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)) method. Changing this would entail changing your Scala program

Once the buffer has reached a threshold size, of the order 10s-100s of KB, increasing FileChannel buffer size may or may not increase performance - it depends on how the program uses the buffer:

- **No**: If the file is read precisely once from end to end: Almost all the time is either waiting for the disk or the processing algorithm
- **Maybe**: If, however, the algorithm frequently scans the file revisiting portions many times, increasing the size *might* improve performance:

  - If modifying or writing the file, a larger buffer can consolidate more writes into a single flush.
  - If reading the file, the operating system will likely have already cached the file (the disk cache) and so any gains are likely marginal. Perversely increasing the size of the JVM might decrease performance by shrinking the effective disk cache size
  - In any case the application would have to be specifically coded to get any benefits, for example by implementing its own logical record pointer onto the cache.

Try **profiling the application** and look for I/O waits (Jprofiler and YourKit are good at this). It may be that file I/O is not actually a problem - don't be a victim of [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). If I/O waits are a significant portion of the total elapsed time, then it might be worth trying out a larger buffer size

**Further information**

https://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/monitoring_direct_buffers

Also be aware that there is a bug reported on the JVM saying that FileChannel is not good at releasing memory. It's detailed in [Prevent OutOfMemory when using java.nio.MappedByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553158/prevent-outofmemory-when-using-java-nio-mappedbytebuffer)

Comment: This is the most awesome answer I've received so far on stackoverflow. Thank you very much indeed!