# 1.7 JVM(32 bit) and windows 32bit os error. map failed

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, bytebuffer, mappedbytebuffer

My program was running fine in windows 64bit, linux 64bit.

But problems occurred when I port the program to **Windows 32bit 2008 SP2(RAM 16GB) with 32bit JDK  (version : 1.7.0_80).**

1. I've tried following

   - java -xmx1024m TestAppServer : Failed with error **java.io.IOException: Map failed**
   - java -xmx512m TestAppServer : Running Successfully
2. I've found following similar issues

   - [How do I avoid mapFailed() error when writing to large file on system with limited memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545683/how-do-i-avoid-mapfailed-error-when-writing-to-large-file-on-system-with-limit)
   - http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6776490

I want to know why this problem occurred when I allocate more heap memory (1024m) and how to fix it?

Comment: Grammar and formatting

Comment: You have already linked to a Q&A and a bug report that answer your question. Of course, the more memory you reserve to the heap, the less address space you have for other purposes. The linked resources already tell you that using a 32 bit environment implies having very little address space (compared to a 1GiB heap) and name the existing  solutions. So what’s your question?