# Java: How to read directory folder, count and display no of files and copy to another folder?

Tags: java, copy, directory

I have to read a folder, count the number of files in the folder (can be of any type), display the number of files and then copy all the files to another folder (specified).

How would I proceed?

Comment: "I am student" means you should complete your homework yourself rather than giving it to your elder brother. As least you should give a try

Comment: I would stop asking vague and unspecific questions, and after some research, I'd start coding. If and when I'm stuck, I'd post here [what I have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and what error I can not get rid of, then with the help, I'd continue my work....

Answer (score 2):

> i Have to read a folder, count the number of files in the folder (can
>   be of any type) display the number of files

You can find all of this functionality in the javadocs for [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

> and then copy all the files to another folder (specified)

This is a bit more tricky. Read: [Java Tutorial > Reading, Writing and Creating of Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)
(note that the mechanisms described there are only available in Java 7 or later. If Java 7 is not an option, refer to one of many previous similar questions, e.g. this one: [Fastest way to write to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576222/342852) )

Answer (score 0):

you have all the sample code here :

http://www.exampledepot.com

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html

```
File dir = new File("directoryName");

String[] children = dir.list();
if (children == null) {
    // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
} else {
    for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
        // Get filename of file or directory
        String filename = children[i];
    }
}

// It is also possible to filter the list of returned files.
// This example does not return any files that start with `.'.
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return !name.startsWith(".");
    }
};
children = dir.list(filter);


// The list of files can also be retrieved as File objects
File[] files = dir.listFiles();

// This filter only returns directories
FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
};
files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

The copying http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CopyDir.html :

```
// Copies all files under srcDir to dstDir.
// If dstDir does not exist, it will be created.
public void copyDirectory(File srcDir, File dstDir) throws IOException {
    if (srcDir.isDirectory()) {
        if (!dstDir.exists()) {
            dstDir.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = srcDir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            copyDirectory(new File(srcDir, children[i]),
                                 new File(dstDir, children[i]));
        }
    } else {
        // This method is implemented in Copying a File
        copyFile(srcDir, dstDir);
    }
}
```

However is very easy to gooole for this stuff :)

Comment: [Don't provide complete solutions with code to Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/147793)

Comment: Anyway is not the complete solution there are snippets...that need small work from him as well...

Comment: The Homework tag is deprecated and forbidden, but the OP wrote "I am student". However, that got removed in one of the edits.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late but below code worked for me. It basically iterates through each file in directory, if found file is a directory then it makes recursive call. **It only gives files count in a directory**.

```
public static int noOfFilesInDirectory(File directory) {
    int noOfFiles = 0;
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            noOfFiles++;
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            noOfFiles += noOfFilesInDirectory(file);
        }
    }
    return noOfFiles;
}
```