# How to read a folder, count the files and copy to new folder

Tags: java, copy, location, directory

A follow up to my previous question - [Java: How to read directory folder, count and display no of files and copy to another folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045326/java-how-to-read-directory-folder-count-and-display-no-of-files-and-copy-to-an), I want to read a folder, count the files in the folder (any file type), display the number of files, then copy it to a new folder. However, I am getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\project\curFolder (Access is denied)
>   C:\project\newFolder already exist: Continuing with process!
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>       at filetransfer.FileTransfer.copyFiles(FileTransfer.java:54)
>       at filetransfer.FileTransfer.checkDir(FileTransfer.java:44)
>       at filetransfer.FileTransfer.readDirectory(FileTransfer.java:29)
>       at filetransfer.FileTransfer.main(FileTransfer.java:12)
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Please keep in mind I'm a student. This is what I have done so far:

```
public class FileTransfer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
         readDirectory();
    }

public static void readDirectory() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        //create new file object with location of folder
        File curFolder = new File("C:/project/curFolder/");
        int totalFiles = 0;
        //for loop to count the files in the directory using listfiles method
        for (File file : curFolder.listFiles()) {
            //determine if the file object is a file
            if (file.isFile()) {
                //count files ++
                totalFiles++;
            }
        }
        //display number of files in directory
        System.out.println("Number of files: " + totalFiles);
        checkDir();
    }

    public static void checkDir() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        //check if destination directory exist, if not create directory
        //create new file object with copy folder destination
        File newFolder = new File("C:/project/newFolder/");
        //Check if folder exist: True: Println with message(true and continuing)
        if (newFolder.exists()) {
            System.out.println(newFolder + " already exist: Continuing with process!");
        } else {
            //False: Create Dir
            newFolder.mkdir();
            System.out.println(newFolder + " created!");
        }
        copyFiles();
    }

    public static void copyFiles() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        //copy files from specified directory to new directory
        File fromCur = new File("C:/project/curFolder/");
        File toNew = new File("C:/project/newFolder/");
        FileInputStream from = null;
        FileOutputStream to = null;
        try {
            from = new FileInputStream(fromCur);
            to = new FileOutputStream(toNew);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = from.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                to.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } finally {
            if (from != null) {
                try {
                    from.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if (to != null) {
                try {
                    to.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does `C:/project/curFolder/` exists in your machine?

Comment: i also have full control over it and using admin account. its not set to read only.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is copying a folder itself, not the files inside it. Try changing this part of your `copyFiles` method:

```
    File fromCur = new File("C:/project/curFolder/");
        File toNew = new File("C:/project/newFolder/");
        FileInputStream from = null;
        FileOutputStream to = null;

    try {

    to = new FileOutputStream(toNew);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;

    for (File fileTemp : fromCur.listFiles()) {
     if (fileTemp.isFile()) {
        from = new FileInputStream(fileTemp);
         while ((bytesRead = from.read(buffer)) != -1) {
          to.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
     }
    }
```

While looping, this will reference to your files **inside** your folder and not the folder itself.

Comment: dont know if im doing something wrong, but im still receiving the same error?

Comment: i now have it exactly like your code, no exception but the files inside the curFolder is not copied to newFolder

I Apologize, this is now confusing me

Comment: any ideas on how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the following line:

```
from = new FileInputStream(fromCur);
```

because `C:\project\curFolder` is a folder and not a file. The exception you are seeing is correct according to the [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29) documentation.

> Throws:
>   **FileNotFoundException** - if the file does not exist, *is a directory* rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading.

(my emphasis in the above quote)

I believe you will probably want to check that the input File [is a directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) and then [list the files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) and copy them one by one.