# Text File error Scanner

Tags: java, text

I'm writing code which deletes a word out of a text file when the user inputs it but I cant seem to get the scanner part to work

```
public static void Option2Method() throws IOException 
{

File inputFile = new File("wordlist.txt");
File tempFile = new File("TempWordlist.txt");
String lineToRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word to remove");
Scanner reader =  new Scanner(inputFile); 
Scanner writer =new Scanner(tempFile);
String currentLine;

while((currentLine = reader.nextLine()) != null)
{
String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
writer.print(currentLine + "\n");
}
reader.close();
writer.close();
inputFile.delete();
tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
}
```

Comment: Where you having problem ?

Comment: Keeps giving an error for writer.print(currentLine + "\n"); It says it cannot find symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner` is not meant to write files, hence does not have a `write()` method. You can use `BufferedWriter`instead.

Example:

```
public static void Option2Method() throws IOException {

    File inputFile = new File("wordlist.txt");
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("TempWordlist.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    File tempFile = new File("TempWordlist.txt");
    String lineToRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word to remove");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String trimmedLine = reader.nextLine().trim();
        if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove))
            continue;

        writer.write(trimmedLine + "\n");
    }

    reader.close();
    writer.close();
    inputFile.delete();
    tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
}
```

Using `PrintWriter`:

```
    File inputFile = new File("wordlist.txt");
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("TempWordlist.txt", true)));

    File tempFile = new File("TempWordlist.txt");
    String lineToRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word to remove");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String trimmedLine = reader.nextLine().trim();
        if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove))
            continue;

        writer.print(trimmedLine + "\n");
    }

    reader.close();
    writer.close();
    inputFile.delete();
    tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

Comment: Well then is there a way to do it with PrintWriter??

Comment: Yes. I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` doesn't have a `print` method. It is used to **scan** a file and **read** data from it.

If you want to write to a file, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576234/1651233) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667865/1651233) or just google "[java write to file](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=java%20write%20to%20file&rlz=1C1CHEU_iwIL474IL474&aq=f&oq=java%20write%20to%20file&aqs=chrome.0.59j60l2j0l3.4604j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)"

Comment: You dont need BufferedReader, you need BufferedWriter