# Java: Files.readAllBytes....is there a method faster than this to get the byte arrays of a file

Tags: java, file, sockets, arrays

I maded a simple java server program that send files to client.

The program works fine but when i load a very big file (1 GB) it takes 2 or 3 minutes for this line of code:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Is there a wat to bypass this or make it faster (maybe by using a library)?

Thank's!

Comment: Why do you load it all into memory? Why don't you stream it?

Comment: more to the point, why not just http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093888/fastest-way-of-reading-relatively-huge-byte-files-in-java

Comment: I guess you could use NIO to read the file faster, but it'll take some effort to develop and test.

Comment: @markspace this method already uses nio.

Comment: What makes you think it *can* be done faster? And why do it at all? Any file can be processed a piece at a time, even XML.

Comment: You also need to note that you're halfway towards not being able to fit the file into memory at all due to 32-bit byte-array size limitations. This is a bad idea.

Comment: ...and, in many cases, loading the big file in chunks means that you can start processing the data while waiting for more to be delivered.

Comment: @MartinJames Exactly, thus saving both time and space.

Comment: Thank you guys, loading the files at pieces make a significant improvement!