# Process a huge file and call a function on every line of the file fast

Tags: java, performance, io, java-stream

I have a file with about 10.000.000 lines of text (yes I have enough memory).
now I want a List of `MyClass` (Constructor is `MyClass(String s)` with every line of the file. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
List<MyClass> help = Files.lines(Paths.get(s))
                          .parallel()
                          .map(MyClass::new)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it takes Years to progress. Any Idea on how to speed up this problem?

Comment: You could add informations about what you are willing to do and what you want to avoid.

Comment: And what is that process of yours? From what it looks you just create a new instance of some class from each line. More worryingly, you should `.close()` that stream of yours: `Files.lines()` is I/O bound.

Comment: Another version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682281/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-line-per-line ?

Comment: @PM77-1 I would say more like *initial* than *another*.

Comment: how can i `.close` this stream? sorry i am new to streams. i just need this list to set to an ListView in a gui

Comment: _Yes I have enough memory?_  A ten million line text file is not very big by today's standards.

Comment: As a very simple optimization you may try `Arrays.asList(Files.lines(...)...toArray(MyClass[]::new))` instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList())`. However having [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, a relevant extract from the documentation of [`Collectors.toList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--):

> [...]There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier)

Now, let us look a little more deeply into a collector's [characteristics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html); we find this:

> public static final Collector.Characteristics CONCURRENT
>
> Indicates that this collector is concurrent, meaning that the result container can support the accumulator function being called concurrently with the same result container from multiple threads.
>
> If a CONCURRENT collector is not also UNORDERED, then it should only be evaluated concurrently if applied to an unordered data source.

Now, nothing guarantees that the collector returned by `Collectors.toList()` is `Concurrent` at all.

Notwithstanding the time which it may take to initiate a new class of yours, the safe bet here would be to assume that this collector *is not* concurrent. But fortunately we have a means to use a concurrent collection instead, as mentioned in the javadoc. So, let's try:

```
.collect(
        Collector.of(CopyOnWriteArrayList::new,
            List::add,
            (o, o2) -> { o.addAll(o2); return o; },
            Function.<List<String>>identity(),
            Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT,
            Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH
        )
    )
```

This may speed things up.

Now, you have another problem. You do not close you stream.

This is little known but a `Stream` (whether of any type or an {Int,Double,Long}Stream for that matter) implements `AutoCloseable`. You want to close streams which are I/O bound and `Files.lines()` is such a stream.

So, try this:

```
final List<MyClass> list;

try (
    final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(...);
) {
    list = lines.parallel().map(MyClass::new)
        .collect(seeAbove);
}
```

Comment: with this Collector Eclipse gives me an error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List<Reciever>`

Comment: Well, um, does it at least speed things up for you? :p

Comment: yes it speed things up but also takes about 10 minutes ... sooo... yeah...how is it possible this task to only use 0.7 of my cpu btw?

Comment: Then what about you think a little higher? For instance, wouldn't you be able to replace your .collect() call with a .forEach() instead?

Comment: .forEach(list::add) ? like this?

Comment: No; what I meant is, is it really necessary to collect all of your newly created objects into a collection to start with? Can't you use them instead to do whatever it is that you need to do? Ie, stream.parallel().map(MyClass:new).forEach( /* do something with instance of MyClass */ )

Comment: The answer is completely misleading. If collector is not CONCURRENT, it [does not mean](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22350288/4856258) that it cannot be used for parallel stream. Special CONCURRENT processing speeds up the unordered collection eliminating the needs to execute the `combiner`. In this case the proposed solution will not use concurrent collection as both source and collector are ordered, so this would actually slow down the process even more.