# Can I use FileReader to read a file containing images and video (say an epub file) and text and is it suggested to do so with respect to perfomance.

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream, epub

I need to parse contents of a epub file and I am trying to see what would be the most efficient way to do it. The epub file may contain images, lot of text and occasionally videos too. Should I go for a FileInputStream or a FileReader?

Comment: Clearly `FileInputStream` if your format is not pure text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As epub uses a ZIP archive structure I would propose to handle it as such. Find a small snippet below which list the content of an epub file.

```
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
env.put("create", "true");

Path path = Paths.get("foobar.epub");
URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());
FileSystem zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
Path root = zipFs.getPath("/");
Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
            BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        print(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
            BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        print(dir);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    private void print(Path file) throws IOException {
        Date lastModifiedTime = new Date(Files.getLastModifiedTime(file).toMillis());
        System.out.printf("%td.%<tm.%<tY %<tH:%<tM:%<tS %9d %s\n", 
                lastModifiedTime, Files.size(file), file);
    }
});
```

sample output

```
01.01.1970 00:59:59         0 /META-INF/
11.02.2015 16:33:44       244 /META-INF/container.xml
11.02.2015 16:33:44      3437 /logo.jpg
...
```

**edit** If you only want to extract files based on their names you could do it like shown in this snippet for the `visitFile(...)` method.

```
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    // if the filename inside the epub end with "*logo.jpg"
    if (file.endsWith("logo.jpg")) {
        // extract the file in directory /tmp/
        Files.copy(file, Paths.get("/tmp/",
            file.getFileName().toString()));
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

Depending on how you want to process the files inside the epub you might also have a look on the `ZipInputStream`.

```
try (ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("foobar.epub"))) {
    for (ZipEntry entry = in.getNextEntry(); entry != null; 
        entry = in.getNextEntry()) {
        System.out.printf("%td.%<tm.%<tY %<tH:%<tM:%<tS %9d %s\n",
                new Date(entry.getTime()), entry.getSize(), entry.getName());
        if (entry.getName().endsWith("logo.jpg")) {
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName())) {
                // process the file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sample output

```
11.02.2013 16:33:44       244 META-INF/container.xml
11.02.2013 16:33:44      3437 logo.jpg
```

Comment: This is a good aproach. One more addition: Method `visitFile` should decide if using an InputStream or a Reader to read the contents of each file.

Comment: Thanks SubOptimal for the comprehensive suggestion. @Little Santi, I did not understand the comment about visitFile deciding the approach to read contents of each file.

Comment: @Zooter I meant that each file must be read either as text (through Reader APIs) or as binary (through Stream APIs). And that decission must be taken within the method `visitFile`.

Comment: @LittleSanti I agree, but this mainly depends on how "Zooter" want to process the files.

Comment: @Zooter I updated my answer to provide another way. Depending on you requirements you need to choose the one which better fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to read a whole file as bytes (and thats what you want if it's not plain text) is to use the [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class:

```
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("example.epub"));
```

Advantages of this method:

- less code = code gets more readable and has less potential for errors
- java cares about opening and closing file

---

**Edit:**

In order to read a file really fast you can use `java.nio` as well. This time [`java.nio.channels.FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

// Load the file
FileChannel c = new FileInputStream("example.epub").getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer byteBuffer = c.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());

// Process the data
buffer.get(myByte, 1120, 50);

// when finished
c.close();
```

This will not read the whole file into memory but creates a link to the file and reads (buffers) only the parts you try to access. It will also recognize changes on the file and always return the latest content.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for the response. But the documentation says that this method server small files better and its not ideal to use it for larger files. I need to read epub files which can go upto 50 MB or more.

Comment: yeah, this depends on how your code will work later on, i won't call 50 MB a larger file, but thats based on the pc it's running on (specially the memory). Of course you can process the file step by step, i will add an example

Comment: As stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9094629/2546444 the example shown in the edit should be able to prepare 2 GB in under 10 milli-seconds, which should be fast enough for you ;)