# Concatenating a number of .txt files in Java

Tags: java, concatenation

I have a number of `.txt` files. I would like to concatenate those and generate a text file.
How would I do it in Java?

---

#### Following is the case

```
file1.txt file2.txt
```

Concatenation results into

```
file3.txt
```

Such that the *contents* of `file1.txt` is followed by `file2.txt`.

Comment: yes i used to do it with  cat in unix command. but i would like to do it in my program.

Comment: @casperOne This is a very real question, several have understood it, and provided useful information, like the pointer to the FileUtils class.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a real question.  Asked exactly what I wanted to know, and the answers below were helpful.

Comment: +1. It is quite legitimate question, given that the shortest pure-Java answer is 11 lines of code. Compare with #cat file1 file2 > file3 in UNIX shell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Read file-by-file and write them to target file. Something like the following:

```
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    byte[] buf = new byte[n];
    for (String file : files) {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        int b = 0;
        while ( (b = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
            out.write(buf, 0, b);
        in.close();
    }
    out.close();
```

Comment: I like this one more as it extensible for more than two files and doesn't have to hold as much in memory.

Comment: @alexr can you extend it a little bit more and explain it step by step?

Comment: The outer loop iterates over files. Inner loop reads the file's content using n-bytes long buffer. Just take a look on any tutorial on java streams for details.

Answer (score 39):

### *Using* Apache Commons IO

You could use the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library. This has the [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class.

```
// Files to read
File file1 = new File("file1.txt");
File file2 = new File("file2.txt");

// File to write
File file3 = new File("file3.txt");

// Read the file as string
String file1Str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file1);
String file2Str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file2);

// Write the file
FileUtils.write(file3, file1Str);
FileUtils.write(file3, file2Str, true); // true for append
```

There are also other methods in this class that could help accomplish the task in a more optimal way (eg using *streams* or *lists*).

### *Using* Java 7+

If you are using Java 7+

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Input files
    List<Path> inputs = Arrays.asList(
            Paths.get("file1.txt"),
            Paths.get("file2.txt")
    );

    // Output file
    Path output = Paths.get("file3.txt");

    // Charset for read and write
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    // Join files (lines)
    for (Path path : inputs) {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
        Files.write(output, lines, charset, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605332/java-nio-filechannel-versus-fileoutputstream-performance-usefulness) describes significantly better performance using Channels instead of reading everything into memory. You can also use Guava's ByteSource.concat to get an InputStream of everything concatenated, then pass it into FileChannel.transferTo

Answer (score 4):

this works fine for me.

```
// open file input stream to the first file file2.txt
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("file1.txt");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1 << 20];  // loads 1 MB of the file
// open file output stream to which files will be concatenated. 
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("file3.txt"), true);
int count;
// read entire file1.txt and write it to file3.txt
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, count);
    os.flush();
}
in.close();
// open file input stream to the second file, file2.txt
in = new FileInputStream("file2.txt");
// read entire file2.txt and write it to file3.txt
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, count);
    os.flush();
}
in.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: Can you explain your code step by step please?

Comment: @JoelBonetR I added some comments explaining this old code. However, I think some answers above are better.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you need one file with the content of other text files? Then, read each and every file(you can do it in a loop), save their content in a StringBuffer/ArrayList, and generate the final .txt file by flushing those saved texts in StringBuffer/ArrayList to the final .txt file.

Don't worry, this is an easy task. Just get used to the given system, then you are OK :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework...

1. Open File 1
2. Open File 2
3. Create/Open File 3
4. Read from File 1 and Write into File 3
5. Close File 1
6. Read From File 2 and Write into File 3
7. Close File 2
8. Close File 3

If you need to know how to create/open/read/write/close files in Java, search for documentation. [That information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) should be widely available.