# How to compare and merge two text files?

Tags: java, merge, diff

I have two files say

```
abc           
cdg
sfh
drt
fgh
```

and another file

```
ahj
yuo
jkl
uio
abc
cdg
```

I want to compare these two files and get output file as

```
abc
cdg
sfh
drt
fgh
ahj
yuo
jkl
uio
```

this is my code

```
public static void MergeFiles(final File priviousModifiedFilesList, final File currentModifiedFilesList,
      final File ModifiedFilesList) {
    FileWriter fstream = null;
    out = null;
    try {
      fstream = new FileWriter(ModifiedFilesList, true);
      out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    }
    catch (IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("merging: " + priviousModifiedFilesList + "\n");
    System.out.println("merging: " + currentModifiedFilesList);
    FileInputStream fis1;
    FileInputStream fis2;
    try {
      fis1 = new FileInputStream(priviousModifiedFilesList);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis1));

      fis2 = new FileInputStream(currentModifiedFilesList);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));

      String Line1;
      String Line2;

      while (((Line1 = bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null)) {

        while ((Line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {

          if (Line1.equals(Line2)) {
            out.write(Line1);
          }

          out.write(Line2);
          out.newLine();
        }
         out.write(Line1);
      }
      bufferedReader1.close();
      bufferedReader2.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.close();
}
```

it writes all the lines from first file and when the lines match it stops.

Comment: And where is the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking programming questions about code you are writing. Currently you've written a set of requirements, which is more appropriate for a contractor-hiring web site. Please show us what you've attempted and where you got stuck. That being said, even your requirements are unclear - it seems like you want to remove duplicates from the merged file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [concatenating a number of .txt files in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675450/concatenating-a-number-of-txt-files-in-java)

Comment: @X.L.Ant I don't think that's a duplicate, because there seems to be some requirement here for de-duplication of output.

Comment: take a look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5283123/1214847

Comment: @Duncan yeah, you're right. My bad. Still NARQ though.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Agreed. I've voted to close as "unclear what you're asking", since the requirements are unclear, as is the current progress made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy:

- Read you first file line by line (you can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for that).
- For each line, write it to the output file (you can use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) for that).
- Also store the line in a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

---

- Read your second file line by line.
- For each line, check if the line is in the `HashSet`.
- If it's not, write it to the output file.

---

- Close your files.