# Making filewriting process even more faster

Tags: java, performance

I am writing the below code that this code basically writes to a file through buffered writer, I am using JDK 1.5, now my query is that basically this code works perfectly and writes to the file , the file is big let say about the final size of the file is about 1GB, now please let me is there any other alternative offered by Java in JDK 1.5 which could make file writer process even more faster and improve the performance?

```
 File file = new File(FilePath + getFileName());
 try (BufferedWriter bw = new  BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
   for (Posuser posuser : totalusers) {
     for (potook bk : books) {
       if ((posuser.getUpdatedBy() == null)
           && (posuser.getUpdateddateformat() == null)) {
         bw.write("aaa"+"\r\n");
       } else if (posuser.getUpdatedBy() == null
                  && posuser.getUpdateddateformat() != null) {
         bw.write("bbb+"\r\n");
       } else if (posuser.getUpdatedBy() != null
                  && posuser.getUpdateddateformat() == null) {
         bw.write("ccc"+"\r\n");
       } else {
         bw.write("ddd"+\r\n");
       }
     }
   }
 } catch (IOException, AnotherException e) {
   logger.error(e.getMessage());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the `java.nio` package. [This SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605332/java-nio-filechannel-versus-fileoutputstream-performance-usefulness) details more info re. performance increases.

> My experience with larger files sizes has been that java.nio is faster
>   than java.io. Solidly faster. Like in the >250% range.

Comment: could you please let me know is nio is there in jdk 1.5

Comment: According to [one study here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/file-copy-java-%E2%80%93-benchmark) the advantage of nio starts mostly disappears once you get to huge files like OP is talking about. @RamKumar - You need to use nio differently in Java 1.5 (no java.nio.files package), but the essentials are there. Take a look at `java.nio.channels`. You'll have to hunt around for some older tutorials on the web that show how to use nio in Java 1.5.

Comment: Well, i thought `NIO` is usable only for files copying. The advantage should be no need to read whole file to memory and then to write it to disk, but just copy it via buffer between two IN/OUT channels. Well, in this case all structures all in memory and they need to be written to disk, so i did not see any improvement.

Answer (score 1):

This should be at least memory efficient. [Blog: String intern](http://plumbr.eu/blog/reducing-memory-usage-with-string-intern) The string `+` is costly operation, you should use `StringBuilder` instead.

```
   final String aaaString = "aaa".intern();
    final String bbbString = "bbb".intern();
    final String cccString = "ccc".intern();
    final String dddString = "ddd".intern();
    final String EOL = "\r\n".intern();

    File file = new File(FilePath + getFileName());
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new  BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
      for (Posuser posuser : totalusers) {
        for (potook bk : books) {
          if ((posuser.getUpdatedBy() == null)
              && (posuser.getUpdateddateformat() == null)) {
            bw.write(aaaString);
            bw.write(EOL);
          } else if (posuser.getUpdatedBy() == null
                     && posuser.getUpdateddateformat() != null) {
            bw.write(bbbString);
            bw.write(EOL);
          } else if (posuser.getUpdatedBy() != null
                     && posuser.getUpdateddateformat() == null) {
            bw.write(cccString);
            bw.write(EOL);
          } else {
            bw.write(dddString);
            bw.write(EOL);
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException, AnotherException e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot these small things matter

Comment: also please suggest if I had (aaaString+bbbString) then how could I make this more memory efficient

Comment: Do not join them just write one by one. `bw.write(aaaString); bw.write(bbbString);`

Comment: @RamKumar - For a single expression, joining with a `StringBuilder` is no more efficient than using string concatenation with `+`. You gain efficiency when you can reuse a `StringBuilder` in place of multiple concatenations in separate statements. But the best approach is to avoid concatenation when it is not needed, as Milan suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough just to use a BufferedWriter, you need to tweak the buffer size (second constructor parameter). The larger the buffer, the most performance you'll get. But remember, if you set the buffer size to 1MB, you'll need to be sure that reserving 1MB of RAM to *every* concurrent call of this code isn't an issue. Also, Brian's answer (java.nio package) is very nice. Combine the two: change to java.nio AND tweak the buffer size until you find the magic number to your use case.

Comment: It might also boost performance to buffer at the stream level as well, rather than using a `FileWriter`.

Comment: @TedHopp Please also adivise what will be the appropriate buffer size that I can enter into the constructor for writing a file of 1 gb

Comment: @RamKumar - It's hard to say for sure; this is best determined by benchmarking and it will vary with your execution environment and the load on your system. The best buffer size is probably some multiple of the disk block size. I believe that the default buffer size for a `BufferedWriter` is 8192 (8KB).