# Java Multithreading Network Connection Performance Advice

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, network-programming, java-stream

I need to have lots of network connections open at the same time(!) and transfer data as fast as possible. Thousands of connections. Right now, I have one thread for each connection and reading charwise from the Inputstream of that connection.
And I have the strong suspicion that the CPU/switching between the thousands of threads *might* impose some performance problems here even though the servers are really slow (low two-digit KB/s), since I've observed that the throughput isn't even close to being proportional to the number of threads.
Therefore I'd like to ask some programmers experienced in parallel programming:
Is it worth rewriting the entire program so that one thread reads from multiple InputStreams in a round robin like fashion? Would that, if there is a speedup, be worth the programming? How many connections per thread? Or do you have another idea for reading really really fast from multiple network input streams?

If I don't read a char, will the server wait to send the next one until I do? What if my thread is sleeping?

Answer (score 2):

> reading charwise

You know data is transmitted in packets right? Reading a single character at a time is very inefficient. Each read has to traverse all the layers from your program to the network stack in the operating system. You should try to read one full segment of data at a time.

> If I don't read a char, will the server wait to send the next one until I do? What if my thread is sleeping?

That's why the operating system has a buffer for incoming data, also called a window. When TCP segments arrive, they are put into the receive buffer. When your program requests to read from the socket, the operating system returns data from the receive buffer. If the receive buffer is full, the packet is lost and has to be sent again.

For more about how TCP works, see https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/
Wikipedia is pretty good but fairly dense
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

> Is it worth rewriting the entire program so that one thread reads from multiple InputStreams in a round robin like fashion? Would that, if there is a speedup, be worth the programming?

What you're describing would require moving from blocking I/O to non-blocking I/O. Non-blocking will require fewer system resources, but it is significantly harder to implement correctly and efficiently. So don't do it unless you have a pressing reason.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll try to get around the charwise reading and try a BufferedReader. I read them using the InputStream.read() method in a while loop. Some question on StackOverflow said that it's still very fast.      Isn't only reading from the BufferedReader when there's something available "non-blocking I/O"? If I just use a LinkedList of my BufferedReaders, reading each one until it's empty, then going to the next? Or is that inefficient? I'll try the BufferedReader-thing first

Comment: BufferedReader will try to read larger blocks of data at a time, so you'll get most of the benefit even if you keep reading one character at a time. It cannot tell you when new data arrives though-that's where you need non blocking io and use selectors as mentioned by the other answer. I'm guessing you're thinking about something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552223/socket-inputstream-blocks-on-available-read

Answer (score 1):

Thousands of threads (and stacks...) are probably too many for the OS scheduler, memory management units, caches...
You need just a few threads (one per CPU) and use a `select()`-based solution
on each of them.
Have a look at `Selector`, `ServerSocketChannel` and `SocketChannel`.
(see pages 30-31 of [https://www.enib.fr/~harrouet/Data/Courses/Memo_Sockets.pdf](https://www.enib.fr/%7Eharrouet/Data/Courses/Memo_Sockets.pdf))

---

Edit (after a question in the comments)

`Selector` is not just a clever algorithm encapsulated in a class.
It relies internally on the `select()` system-call (or equivalent,
there are many).
The operating system is aware of a set of file-descriptors (communication
means) it has to watch and, as soon as something happens on one (or
several) of them, it wakes up the process (or thread) which is blocked
on this selector.
The idea is to stay blocked as long as possible (to save resources) and
to be waken-up only on when something useful has to be done with incoming
(there are variants) data.

In your current implementation, you use thousands of threads which are
all blocked on a `read()`/`recv()` operation because you cannot know
beforehand which connection will be the next one to deliver something.
On the other hand, with a `select()`-based implementation, a single
thread can be blocked watching **many** connections at the same time
but will only react to handle the few ones which just delivered new
data.

So I suggest that you start a pool of few threads (one per CPU for example) and as soon as the main program accepts a new incoming
connection it chooses one of them (you can keep a count for each
of them) in order to make it in charge of this new connection.
All of this requires the proper synchronisation of course and probably
a trick (a special file descriptor in the selector for example) in
order to wake-up a blocked thread when it is assigned a new connection.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, Selectors sound useful. I guess it's faster than a self-written class for reading from multiple streams?

Comment: @Tobs40 This is OS-related. The answer is edited to explain further.

Comment: AHHHH ok, thank you :-) This sounds like a pretty good speedup!