# Read files on hadoop with java nio FileChannel

Tags: java, hadoop, nio

I am trying to read some hadoop files using nio. My question is how can I pass a FileSystem to FileChannel. The reason I want to use that is because, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605332/java-nio-filechannel-versus-fileoutputstream-performance-usefulness), nio is faster.

Comment: It's only even potentially faster *if* you can use it, and as you can't use it in assocation with a Hadoop `FileSystem`, it isn't faster at all.

Comment: That's why I am asking if anyone has a solution, then I can test if it's really faster.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you don't need to pass filesystem in FileChannel. You can extend `FileChannel` to accept the given filesystem. You can go through [this repo](https://github.com/damiencarol/jsr203-hadoop) to read more about it. You can see in this [given file](https://github.com/damiencarol/jsr203-hadoop/blob/master/src/main/java/hdfs/jsr203/HadoopFileChannel.java) how FileChannel is extended.